# CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: unable to open database file

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to use the gii code generator to create models. I was able to access the gii code generator on my browser. However, when I click on the 'Model Genetator' I get the CDbException which says this 'DbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file'. Any one able to help me out with this? I am just getting started that's why I don't have enough reputation to upload photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your protected/main.php file

find this and put database name and password there

```
'class' => 'CDbConnection',
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii',
'username' => 'rootnew',
'password' => '',
```

if you have not created database go to phpmyadmin and create database.

Answer (score 0):

What Yii version are you using? 
If you are using Yii 1.1.16 go to your webroot / protected / config / database.php
You will find what kamlesh.bar said

```
'class'=>'CDbConnection',
'connectionString'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname={DATABASE}',
'username' => '{DBUSER}',
'password' => '{DBPASSWORD}',
'emulatePrepare'=>true,  // needed by some MySQL installations
```

In Yii 2 you have to edit the db.php file and edit:

```
<?php
 return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname={DATABASE}',
    'username' => '{DBUSER}',
    'password' => '{DBPASSWORD}',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

I wish this solve your problem